# Using JQuery For a Universal Nav Bar?

Tags: jquery, html

I've been reading up on how to create a separate navigation bar that is maintained in a single file for easy updating. After assessing some options, I decided on JQuery as, at the moment, I don't have a site and am just learning how to code.

I'm using this code on the index.html file (followed by the unordered list in a separate nav.html file):

```js
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#menu").load("nav.html"); 
    });
  </script>
```

```html
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Page1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page4</a></li>
    </ul>
```

And then calling it with this on index.html:

```html
<nav>
   <div id="menu">
</nav>
```

But nothing happens, the nav bar isn't visible on my page.

Any suggestions as to what's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: You should close your `div` tag as currently it's invalid HTML.  Change `<div id="menu">` to `<div id="menu"></div>`.

Comment: No errors. And whoops, closed the tag now! Still no luck though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8q243cz6/)

`$('#menu').load` requires the source to be running on a server.
It didn't work for you probably because you are not running it on a server.

Comment: Thanks! That would definitely be why then. Is there any way to get it working without a server?

Comment: I don't think so. However it's easy to start a simple server. There's one line command in python that starts a simple server.

Comment: Oh, terrific. I'll look into it. Thank you!